# How to find a difference between time and prompting a message in case of a blank cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

Here I need to try to find the difference between the created date and the initial approval.  I've tried the following formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(IF(AND(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3)),"Enter dates"), IF(ISBLANK(B3),"Enter Created date"),IF(ISBLANK(C3),"Enter Initial Approval date",IF(C3<B3,"Enter correct date",C3-B3))),"Dates are Missing")
```

When the created date cell is blank, the formula is not prompting the error message.

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by prompt? Your image showing results. If you need prompt message then you have to use `VBA` macro.

Comment: As B5 cell is empty, I'd like to populate a message "Enter Created Date" in E5 ..

Comment: Anyway shouldn't "Created date" be "Creation day"?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3)),"Enter dates",IF(ISBLANK(B3),"Enter Created date",IF(ISBLANK(C3),"Enter Initial Approval date",IF(C3<B3,"Enter correct date",C3-B3)))),"Dates are missing")
```

The following one also:

1. checks if one or both reference are returning error and if so it checks if it's a reference error of another kind of error and report the missing reference/s or the erroneous reference/s;
2. cheks if one or both reference have numbers inside of them, otherwise it returns the invalid reference/s.

   ```
   =IF(AND(ISERROR(B3),ISERROR(C3)),IF(AND(ERROR.TYPE(B3)=4,ERROR.TYPE(B3)=4),"Dates are missing","Erroneous dates"),IF(AND(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3)),"Enter dates",IF(ISBLANK(B3),IF(ISERROR(C3),IF(ERROR.TYPE(C3)=4,"Initial approval date is missing","Erroneous initial approval date"),"Enter Created date"),IF(ISBLANK(C3),IF(ISERROR(B3),IF(ERROR.TYPE(B3)=4,"Created date is missing","Erroneous created date"),"Enter Initial Approval date"),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B3),ISNUMBER(C3)),IF(C3<B3,"Enter correct date",C3-B3),IF(ISNUMBER(B3),"Invalid initial approval date",IF(ISNUMBER(C3),"Invalid created date","Invalid dates")))))))
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I tried following ..

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B3),ISBLANK(C3)),C3-B3,IF(ISBLANK(B3),"Enter Created Date",IF(ISBLANK(C3),"Enter Initial Approval",C3-B3)))

Comment: That's a way simplier formula for a way simplier outcome than what your initial formula was suggesting to be intended for. But if that's what you were looking for, ok. Guess i'll have to keep it simple next time. ^^